# Sign In With Apple AuthorizationError in Mac Catalyst? (Works great on iPad)

Tags: macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst, sign-in-with-apple

I've got an iPad app that runs on the Mac in "Scale Interface to Match iPad" mode. Mostly SwiftUI.

The Sign In With Apple button leads to this error coming out of the console and nothing happening on screen when run on a Mac.

```
[core] No window got from UINSSharedApplicationDelegate
[core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7071 "(null)"
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)
```

I'm unable to find any documentation for these error codes and my latest Mac App Store build has been rejected because this isn't working, so I'm trying to figure out if there is something that needs to be done slightly differently when working on Catalyst.

This works great on iPhone and iPad and my code for launching SIWA is the same on both:

```swift
    func onButtonTapped() {
        let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = []
        self.controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        controller.delegate = SIWAListener.shared
        controller.performRequests()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed what was missing was presentationContextProvider as mentioned here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/7099